# How can I change the default background picture to one of my mac permanently to one of my own

Tags: wallpaper

How can I change the default background picture to one of my own **permanently** in Ventura on my iMac?

Comment: Which background picture, the one shown before login or the Finder background?

Comment: System Settings > Wallpaper.

Comment: When you boot up, that’s the picture I wish to change it’s the log in screen